# Cassandra new node bootstrapping while it should not

Tags: cassandra

I'm adding a new datacenter to an existing cluster and I'm following [this "procedure"](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html).

However the first node I start is apparently bootstrapping: the `load` information from `nodetool status` keeps growing...

I added

```
auto_boostrap: false
```

in `cassandra.yaml`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `auto_bootstrap: false` , you tell the node not to bootstrap - that DOESNT tell it not to take any writes. What is the replication settings for the new datacenter? Did you already enable it in the various keyspaces? If so, it will participate in writes.

When you say you see the load increasing, is it streaming? Do you see files being transferred in `nodetool netstats`? Is the node `Up, Normal` or `Up, Joining`?

Comment: You're right my replication factor was already set for the new DC so I assume I was seeing the new data coming in and not a real bootstrapping. It wasn't streaming (`nodetool netstats`).

Answer (score 0):

check your cassandra-rackdc.properties and don't forget to change DC(dc=DC1) name in that file if you are creating a new datacenter otherwise it will consider the new node as of same datacenter.